# MacBook Pro Color Profile

Tags: macbook-pro, color

I have a MacBookPro7,1 and the color profile for it is just horrible. All yellow and wrong looking.

However, when the Mac is first booting, right before it gives control over to the login window, the colors look fine. Right as the controls become interactive, the color profile flips to the yellow one.

Is there a way to find out which profile is the one that's used during boot?

I know I can set it with ColorSync Utility, but I can't figure out which it is.